# Counter with 4 flip flops jk synchronous from 3 to 13

Tags: flipflop, counter, synchronous

I have to create a counter with 4 flip flops jk synchronous. The counter shall count in this order: 3 to 13 and then to 3 to 13 and so on..

I have to use logisim simulator.

Until now what i´ve achieved is this: 
it counts from 0 to 13 but i dont know how to to add the count 3 at the beggining...
Could someone show me the simulation done on the logisim?

[image]